# Why python numpy is slowly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

example, for `gr = np.array([5, 4, 3, 5, 2])` and `genx = np.array(["femy_gen_m", "my_gen_m", "my_gen_m", "femy_gen_m", "my_gen_m"])`, the output is `{'my_gen_m': 3.0, 'femy_gen_m': 5.0}`. Hint. use mean from `numpy`.

I write the function for already written unittest by teacher, but face with slow function processing.

Attached my code below.

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np


#mycode
def mean_by_redneg(gr, genx):
    result = {}
    my_gen_m_sum, femy_gen_m_sum = [], []
    for index, element in enumerate(genx):
        if element == 'my_gen_m':
            my_gen_m_sum.append(gr[index])
        if element == 'femy_gen_m':
            femy_gen_m_sum.append(gr[index])
    result['my_gen_m'] = np.asarray(my_gen_m_sum).mean()
    result['femy_gen_m'] = np.asarray(femy_gen_m_sum).mean()
    return result

#check the function
def test(gr, genx, outp):
    ret = mean_by_redneg(np.array(gr), np.array(genx))
    assert np.isclose(ret['femy_gen_m'], outp['femy_gen_m'])
    assert np.isclose(ret['my_gen_m'], outp['my_gen_m'])


test([5, 4, 3, 5, 2], ["femy_gen_m", "my_gen_m", "my_gen_m", "femy_gen_m", "my_gen_m"], {'my_gen_m': 3.0, 'femy_gen_m': 5.0})
test([1, 0] * 10, ['femy_gen_m', 'my_gen_m'] * 10, {'femy_gen_m': 1, 'my_gen_m': 0})
test(range(100), ['femy_gen_m', 'my_gen_m'] * 50, {'femy_gen_m': 49.0, 'my_gen_m': 50.0})
test(list(range(100)) + [100], ['my_gen_m'] * 100 + ['femy_gen_m'], {'my_gen_m': 49.5, 'femy_gen_m': 100.0})


def bm_test(a, b):
    xx = 0
    yy = 0
    im = 0
    fi = 0
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        if x != y:
            xx += x
            yy += x
            im += 1
            fi += 1
    return xx + yy


N = int(1E5)

gr = np.array([1.1] * N + [2.2] * N)
genx = np.array(['my_gen_m'] * N + ['femy_gen_m'] * N)

bm = timeit("assert np.isclose(mean_by_redneg(gr, genx)['my_gen_m'], 1.1)",
                   "from __main__ import np, mean_by_redneg, gr, genx",
                   number=1)
reference_bm = timeit("bm_test(gr, genx)",
                             "from __main__ import bm_test, gr, genx",
                             number=1)

assert reference_bm > bm * 10, "too slow"
```

Do you have any idea how to do that work faster?
p.s. Thank you for your time

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for improvements, you should consider to ask your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: yes, the code is works. Trying to post the same question on your link

Comment: This is a fine `numpy` vectorization question folks.

Answer (score 0):

The vectorized way to do this in `numpy` is much simpler than your loopy code.  The heart of it would be something like:

```
out = {}
for gen in ['Male', 'Female']:
    out[gen] = grades[genders == gen].mean()
```

How this works:

`genders == gen` resolves to an array of `True` and `False` called a 'boolean index'.  when `grades` is indexed by it, it returns the values of `grades` that correspond to the locations in the index that are `True`.  So when `gen` is `'Male'`, `grades[genders == gen]` corresponds to the grades corresponding to `'Male'`s.  Once you've resolved that array, you use its `.mean()` method to calculate the mean, and assign it to the dictionary.

This is significantly faster since the iteration/indexing part is completed in the compiled `c` code that is the backend of `numpy`, instead of interpreted `python` code.

Comment: wow, using a range of indexes without iteration is powerful. Your code suggestion works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function:

```
def mean_by_gender2(grades, genders):
    return { g: grades[genders == g].mean() for g in np.unique(genders) }
```

Comparison of execution times (using *%timeit*) shows:

1. Admittedly, for a very short test data (5 items in each array), your solution
   is faster (yours: 36 µs and mine: 52.9 µs).
2. But if you take a longer test data (100 items in each array), then my solution
   is better (yours: 99.5 µs and mine: 62.6 µs).

For yet longer source data the advantage of my solution should be more apparent.